# add actions in the contextual chatbot

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, chatbot

I am developing a contextual chatbot (Python, bag of words, tensorflow) based on a tutorial,
https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077

Here is the JSON file that defines the intent,

```
{"intents": [
  {"tag": "greeting",
    "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
    "responses": ["Hello, thanks for visiting", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
    "context_set": ""
  },
  {"tag": "goodbye",
    "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye"],
    "responses": ["See you later, thanks for visiting", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."]
  },
  {"tag": "thanks",
    "patterns": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful"],
    "responses": ["Happy to help!", "Any time!", "My pleasure"]
  },
  {"tag": "hours",
    "patterns": ["What hours are you open?", "What are your hours?", "When are you open?" ],
    "responses": ["We're open every day 9am-9pm", "Our hours are 9am-9pm every day"]
  },
  {"tag": "mopeds",
    "patterns": ["Which mopeds do you have?", "What kinds of mopeds are there?", "What do you rent?" ],
    "responses": ["We rent Yamaha, Piaggio and Vespa mopeds", "We have Piaggio, Vespa and Yamaha mopeds"]
  },
  {"tag": "payments",
    "patterns": ["Do you take credit cards?", "Do you accept Mastercard?", "Are you cash only?" ],
    "responses": ["We accept VISA, Mastercard and AMEX", "We accept most major credit cards"]
  },
  {"tag": "opentoday",
    "patterns": ["Are you open today?", "When do you open today?", "What are your hours today?"],
    "responses": ["We're open every day from 9am-9pm", "Our hours are 9am-9pm every day"]
  },
  {"tag": "rental",
    "patterns": ["Can we rent a moped?", "I'd like to rent a moped", "How does this work?" ],
    "responses": ["Are you looking to rent today or later this week?"],
    "context_set": "rentalday"
  },
  {"tag": "today",
    "patterns": ["today"],
    "responses": ["For rentals today please call 1-800-MYMOPED", "Same-day rentals please call 1-800-MYMOPED"],
    "context_filter": "rentalday"
  }
]
```

Now I am adding another intent, "callback" which should collect name and phone number (to save it in db/spreadsheet)

```
{"tag": "callback",
        "patterns": ["call","contact","contact me","call me","enquiry","callback"],
        "responses": ["What is your name ?","What is your phone number ?"],
        "context_filter": "enquiry"
      }
```

With this "callback" intent, bot has to collect both name and phone number,once it is collected, it should do the action of saving it in a spreadsheet.

But I am struck here to collect two mandatory fields and adding action to the Bot. Can anyone help me here to work this out ?

Comment: do you want your bot to ask for the phone number and name of both but it's asking only one either phone or name.... is this your issue ?